# Change unique key together in mysql

Tags: mysql, unique

I have in my MYSQL table a unique key and i want to add to it.

```
UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`account_id`)
```

and i want to add another

```
UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`account_id`,`pet_id`)
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE your_table 
   DROP INDEX user_id, 
   ADD UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`account_id`,`pet_id`)
```

Comment: Somewhat confusingly, the name of the unique key is in a separate namespace than the column name, so they can be same string but have totally separate meanings. (Stylistically, I prefer to pretend they're in the same namespace to avoid human assumption errors.) In case it's not obvious, you can split these statements apart into two `ALTER TABLE`s.

Answer (score 2):

Drop the first key and then create the new one.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to change field 'uniq_key' which empty

```
UPDATE your_table  SET `uniq_key`= CONCAT(`user_id`, account_id, pet_id) WHERE  `uniq_key`= ''
```